# Is there a problem for TexStudio 3.01 on Mac?

Tags: texstudio, mac

I do not succeed with downloading TexStudio 3.01 from https://www.texstudio.org and use it with MacAir, and the product is identified as malware. I have installed and used earlier versions of Texstudio including 2.12.22.

I have tried the advice of control clicking the icon, and then open, in order to sidestep the mis-identification of malware, but that did not help.

Is there a way to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. The solution is to right click on the app's icon and select `Open` from the popup menu. You will then be presented with a window asking you to click the `Open` button if you're sure you want to open the application. This is mentioned on the TeXstudio download page next to the macOS download section.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, even though I at this point reverted to my wireless Mac mouse and indeed did ctrl click and expressed that I wanted to open nevertheless.

Comment: Very strange, as I downloaded and installed TeXstudio specifically to answer your question. I'm wondering whether there is something different about your system compared to mine.

Comment: I don't know, but sometimes there are inscrutable issues with preferences or whatever which are difficult to understand.